# JDBC DataRow Equivalent

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mapping

I'm working a project where I would like to create an empty row in a table, then be able to pass it around where it will be loaded with data.

example -

```
insert(DomainObject obj) {
    // connect to DB
    // create new row
    // call methods in hierarchy that insert data into row 
        // such as save(DomainObject obj, DataRow row)
    // commit
}
```

I've been trying to use JdbcRowSet, but I'm not sure if that is the right way of doing this, and things are starting to get messy with that approach anyway.

EDIT: In this particular situation, I do not want to use any frameworks or ORMs. Just plain old JDBC.

Comment: In JDBC you assign values to individual columns during an insert.  If you want to insert a logical record you can look into using something like Hibernate, which maps an object to a row.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only plain JDBC, then there is not really such a thing. You could try to use a row set, but - afaik - they aren't really meant for that, and in my (limited) experience the row set reference implementation included with Java is a buggy fiasco that should be avoided.

You either need to use an ORM like Hibernate, or a library like jOOQ, or spring-jdbc (although even those don't really work the way you want).

That said, your way of working is the reverse what - in my opinion - is the usual way: first collect the data, and then insert it into the database. If that is not feasible for some reason, then you first collect the minimal amount of data, insert it, then collect the rest of the data and update the database.

Comment: Could I pass a PreparedStatement around? In each mapping class, I would set the appropriate parameters.

Comment: @hrazzer You could, but it would be a leaky abstraction that would make testing harder, and would intimately tie a lot of your code to JDBC.